# Debounce function triggers immediately on keyup, instead it must trigger after one second

Tags: javascript, callback, settimeout, debouncing

Am trying to implement custom debounce function which must alert whatever data user has typed in a textbox after one second delay (After user has stopped typing). What am I doing wrong? It triggers the alert() immediately with single character.

```js
function debounce(func, timeout) {
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(this, args);
    }, timeout);
  };
}

function saveInput(args) {
  alert(args); //This triggers immediately
}
const processChange = (event) => {
  debounce(saveInput(event.target.value), 1000);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="processChange(event)" />
```

Can you guys suggest if I miss anything here?

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me. However myInput is a global variable here.

```js
function debounce(callback, delay) {
        let timeout;
        return function () {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(callback, delay);
        }
    }

    const myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");

    function helloInput() {
        alert(myInput.value); 
    }

    myInput.addEventListener(
        "keyup",
        debounce(helloInput, 1000)
    );

    myInput.focus();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
```